# How to prevent LTR layout from being forced to RTL on certain Android devices?

Tags: android, android-layout, right-to-left, bidi

After implementing RTL support in my app a user reported that LTR text is being forced as RTL on Arabic locales. This looks as follows:

[image: LTR text incorrectly forced as RTL]

Notice how the text is right-aligned, even though it should be left-aligned.

I have been told by the user that this error is only present on

- Huawei Y5 Prime 2018 Version 8.1.0
- and LG G3 Version 6.0.0

it is *not present* on Samsung Galaxy J7 Version 6.0.1, or the Android Emulator with SDK 23, 26, 27, 28. There it renders LTR correctly in RTL locales as seen in this screenshot:

[image: LTR text displayed correctly in RTL locale]

I am unable to reproduce it in the emulator - there LTR text is displayed left-aligned while RTL text (arabic in this case) is correctly displayed right-aligned. I suspect that the root cause is that certain OEMs have added code to force RTL layouts in RTL locales.

Note that since my app is an RSS feed reader, I have no control of the actual text being displayed so I am forced to rely on the Bidi-algorithms (which work fine! Except for these devices).

I specify `android:supportsRtl="true"` in the manifest:

```
<application
      android:allowBackup="true"
      android:name=".FeederApplication"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:supportsRtl="true"
      android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
...
</application>
```

[link to full manifest](https://gitlab.com/spacecowboy/Feeder/blob/24ae13ee4907564f406631bf009c6a3d0d3935b6/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml)

And this is the layout from the screenshot:

```
<com.nononsenseapps.feeder.views.ObservableScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context="com.nononsenseapps.feeder.ui.ReaderFragment">

  <!-- Action bar is overlayed, so add some padding -->
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/keyline_1"
    android:paddingTop="?actionBarSize"
    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/keyline_1"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">


    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/story_title"
      style="@style/TextAppearance.Reader.Title"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
      android:textDirection="anyRtl"
      android:textIsSelectable="true"
      android:transitionName="title"
      tools:text="@tools:sample/cities" />

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/story_feedtitle"
      style="@style/TextAppearance.Reader.Author"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
      android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
      android:textDirection="locale"
      android:textIsSelectable="true"
      tools:text="CowboyProgrammer" />

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/story_author"
      style="@style/TextAppearance.Reader.Author"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
      android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
      android:textDirection="locale"
      android:textIsSelectable="true"
      tools:text="Jonas, Sep 14 2015" />

    <com.nononsenseapps.feeder.views.LinkedTextView
      android:id="@+id/story_body"
      style="@style/TextAppearance.Reader.Body"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
      android:minHeight="300dp"
      android:textDirection="anyRtl"
      android:textIsSelectable="true"
      tools:text="@tools:sample/lorem/random" />
  </LinearLayout>


</com.nononsenseapps.feeder.views.ObservableScrollView>
```

In case you're wondering where the ImageView is - there isn't any. The image you see in the screenshot is included as an `ImageSpan` inside the `LinkedTextView`.

I use `anyRtl` to get correct formatting on mixed text. The default behavior (`firstStrong`) will render text as left-justified if it starts with an English word otherwise. This is the code setting the text on the TextViews:

```
val viewModel = getFeedItemViewModel(_id)
viewModel.liveItem.observe(this, androidx.lifecycle.Observer {
    rssItem = it

    rssItem?.let { rssItem ->
        setViewTitle()

        // feedDisplayTitle is a SpannableString
        mFeedTitleTextView.text = rssItem.feedDisplayTitle

        rssItem.pubDate.let { pubDate ->
            rssItem.author.let { author ->
                when {
                    author == null && pubDate != null ->
                        mAuthorTextView.text = getString(R.string.on_date,
                                pubDate.withZone(DateTimeZone.getDefault())
                                        .toString(dateTimeFormat))
                    author != null && pubDate != null ->
                        mAuthorTextView.text = getString(R.string.by_author_on_date,
                                // Must wrap author in unicode marks to ensure it formats
                                // correctly in RTL
                                unicodeWrap(author),
                                pubDate.withZone(DateTimeZone.getDefault())
                                        .toString(dateTimeFormat))
                    else -> mAuthorTextView.visibility = View.GONE
                }
            }
        }
    }
})

viewModel.liveImageText.observe(this, androidx.lifecycle.Observer {
    // the liveImageText is a SpannableString
    bodyTextView.text = it
})

// [...]

fun Fragment.unicodeWrap(text: String): String =
        BidiFormatter.getInstance(getLocale()).unicodeWrap(text)

fun Fragment.getLocale(): Locale? =
        context?.getLocale()

fun Context.unicodeWrap(text: String): String =
        BidiFormatter.getInstance(getLocale()).unicodeWrap(text)

fun Context.getLocale(): Locale =
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            resources.configuration.locales[0]
        } else {
            @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
            resources.configuration.locale
        }
```

[link to full file](https://gitlab.com/spacecowboy/Feeder/blob/24ae13ee4907564f406631bf009c6a3d0d3935b6/app/src/main/java/com/nononsenseapps/feeder/ui/ReaderFragment.kt#L89)

As I've said, I don't control the text to display, I mereley convert the (possibly HTML-formatted) text to a `SpannableString` before displaying ([using this code](https://gitlab.com/spacecowboy/Feeder/blob/24ae13ee4907564f406631bf009c6a3d0d3935b6/app/src/main/java/com/nononsenseapps/feeder/ui/text/HtmlToSpannedConverter.kt)).

So, as the title says, does anyone know of a way to add a workaround for the specific devices where this error occurs?

Comment: Post your layout and manifest.  We can't see if you're making an error or not without code.

Comment: Added layout and manifest details as requested

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that your user has the app in RTL language and the device just omits the response of the Bidi-algorithm when plotting the text in some cases?

Comment: Anything is possible but as I said - it's device specific (and I don't have access to any of the devices) and I'm asking the community if anyone has experienced something similar and how they mitigated it.

Comment: hi, @JonasKalderstam were you able to find a fix for this? Do you mind sharing it please?

Comment: No changes. I still suspect it's certain OEM devices misbehaving in some way and I have no way to verify that.

Comment: Do you have a link that shows such devices forcing rendering to RTL ? I have a huawei and m facing the same issue too with text rendering.

Comment: It was long time ago, I'm sorry I don't have any sample code